# SeekBar Android crash Java

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I just started learning android development using android studio, and i finished the "Starting another activity" , I tried practicing on what I've learned by changing the code a bit and messing with it.
(The tutorial was about displaying text sent by another activity)

So i added a *seekBar* in order to change the text size. After i send the text to another activity using an intent it crashes, but if i remove the *seekBar* listener , it works fine.

DisplayMessageActivity.java:

```
package com.keddy.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public SeekBar _seekbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //Getting the intent received by some other activity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);


        //Text view initialization
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        //Showing text on screen
        setContentView(textView);

        _seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

        _seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Progress Changing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Started Tracking",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Progress Stopped Changing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

I included the onCreate() method only , because that was the only thing I've changed.

activity_display_message.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.keddy.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've searched around and saw the reason was NullPointerException , but i dont know how to fix it , since i have no experience with Java nor Android Development.

if you find a solution please provide:

- Code Example
- How to avoid it again
- Why did it happen

Any help whatsoever will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  setContentView(textView);
```

to

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
```

You must `setContentView(...)` and after add `_seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are adding textview in your Content

```
i.e. setContentView(textview);
```

Your activity is unable to find seekbar1 view. This is the reason why your app is crashing.

Instead of adding textview in Javacode add in xml and use it same way you are using seekbar, and change setContentView(textView) to `setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_file_name);`